# GridView checkbox dissapears on Edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an updatable grid and everything works fine except for the `IsPrimary` field which is of `bit` datatype. As of now, the `ItemTemplate` shows `True` or `False` for `Checked/Unchecked`, but clicking entering the `EditItemTemplate` on the `GridView` makes the checkbox disappear entirely.

Things I tried, but with no luck:

`Checked='<%#Eval("IsPrimaryMachine").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>'`

`Checked ='<%#Boolean.Parse((Eval("IsPrimaryMachine").ToString()))%>'`

The code:

```
<%--PrimaryCheck--%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Primary" SortExpression="IsPrimary">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsPrimary" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsPrimary") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsPrimary" runat="server" 
             Checked='<%#Bind("IsPrimary")%>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The thing is, I need to only use the front end for this. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ItemTemplate and `EditItemTemplate` controls had o have `Checked` and `Text` inside for the display to be working properly.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsPrimary" runat="server" CssClass=""
    Checked='<%# Eval("IsPrimary") %>'
    Text='<%# Eval("IsPrimary") %>'
    onclick="return false;"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your column name correctly is it **"IsPrimaryMachine" or "IsPrimary"**

The below part will work

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Primary" SortExpression="IsPrimary">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblIsPrimary" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsPrimary") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>                       
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsPrimary" runat="server" 
                                        Checked='<%#Eval("IsPrimary").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>


</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I was changing the names to see if I was misspelling things so I tried IsPrimaryMachine but it still is not working for some reason. It just does not appear.

Comment: Please share complete code for grid edit/update/edit cancel events. Also share html of complete grid control.